# Segue related functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know, I can programmtically do segue action by using:

```
-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:
```

I also know the other segue related method on UIViewController, `-prepareForSegue:sender:`, in which I can do customization on the destination view controller.

But I am wondering, which one is called first?

say in a scenario, there is **ViewControllerOne** that has a button which triggers the `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` , then goes to **ViewControllerTwo**.

Comment: So try it? Also, reason tells us noone can prepare for something that didn't happen yet.

Comment: If you drag the segue from button on ViewControllerOne's view to ViewControllerTwo's view, you need NOT to call performSegueWithIdentifier but prepareForSegue of ViewControllerOne will be called. You can also assign an IBAction for your button, do whatever you want, and call performSegueWithIdentifier in order to trigger the segue programatically, and it do calls prepareForSegue before ViewControllerTwo show up (forgot its before or after viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, you'd better test).

Comment: Im not sure get you im afraid ... you hit the button that has the segue but it also has an IBAction where you want to change its 'target' by manually performSegue

Answer (score 0):

The first is `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and actually this is the one you performed.

The second call you mentioned `prepareForSegue:sender:` is a delegate call, which you are not forced to implement

Comment: I know that. I am wondering in practice which one calls first with the precondition that I am using these two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Got it myself:

```
Before performSegueWithIdentifier
Before prepareForSegue
After prepareForSegue.
After performSegueWithIdentifier
```